# What is the distribution of the number of defective parts?

Tags: probability

In a mass production line, the probability of a defect in a
any piece is 1%. For a batch of 100 pieces taken at random,
What is the distribution of the number of defective parts?

I think its a binomial distribution

And then ask what is the most likely number of defects? but i cant understand at all for what is asking

and then ask what is the expected value and i think its $(0.01)*100=1$

but i dont know

Comment: It is a binomial distribution.  See [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), 
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$  From [Linearity of Expected Value](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/), your computation of the expected value is also correct.  You can use the binomial distribution article that I linked to to compute $p(k) = $ the probability of exactly $k$ defects, where $k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots, 100\}$.  ...see next comment

Comment: The easiest way to compute the most likely number of defects is to assume, based on the probability of a specific part being defective equaling $0.01,$ that the most likely number of defects is some number $k \leq 3$.  Then, use the binomial formula to explicitly calculate the probability of having exactly $k$ defects, for $k \in \{0,1,2,3\}.$  This will expand your intuition to the point where you are confident that $k$ must be $\leq 3$.  Therefore, this approach will give you the most likely number of defects.

Comment: By the way: my previous comments assumed that a part being defective is an independent event, with respect to other parts possibly being defective.

Answer (score 1):

Your guesses are right (assuming that probabilities are independent and there's no underlying mechanism, etc.)

The probability of any single part being defective is $p = 0.01$, so whether a randomly selected part is defective is distributed as $Bernoulli(0.01)$. So if I draw 100 parts at random (with a simple random sample of some form), then the total number of defective parts in my sample is $N \sim Bin(100, 0.01)$.

If you're asked for the *most likely* number of defective parts, then you're being asked to find the value of $n$ for which $P(N = n)$ is a maximum. Since the binomial distribution is unimodal, that means finding the value of $n$ where $P(N = n - 1) \leq P(N = n) \leq P(N = n + 1)$, which you can figure out by comparing those adjacent probabilities with the expression for binomial probabilities.